# Maximum RAM for Intel N100?

Tags: memory, specifications, intel

I'm searching for a low-power board for my own home server, but there is something I don't understand about the Intel N100:

- [ASRock states it supports 32GB of RAM](https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/N100DC-ITX/#Specification)
- [Intel states the maximum RAM is 16GB](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/231803/intel-processor-n100-6m-cache-up-to-3-40-ghz.html)
- [People on Geizhals are saying 32GB works](https://geizhals.at/?sr=2953079,-1,10354626&pg=1#10354626) (Austrian language)
- [From this Super User thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1696524/can-a-cpu-support-more-ram-than-specified-by-intel), I see that it *depends*, which confuses me even more

So my question is, is anybody running an N100 with 32GB of RAM? If yes, what RAM did you use? And can anybody explain why different sources disagree on this?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's entirely possible and there are similar reports of using more than the stated amount by Intel.

Comment: lots of things are possible but not "supported". when you are in that territory, it always depends.

Comment: The motherboard specs are correct

Comment: Ramhound: Did you test yourself? What makes you say this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Intel N100 specs](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/231803/intel-processor-n100-6m-cache-up-to-3-40-ghz.html)
say this:

```
Max Memory Size (dependent on memory type)    16 GB
```

Note especially this part : "dependent on memory type".

In the Redit post
[What is the real max memory size supported by the N100?](https://www.reddit.com/r/intel/comments/13npvng/what_is_the_real_max_memory_size_supported_by_the/),
there were made several observations:

> Since it's derived from alder lake, my guess is it can actually do 64GB per channel, and it has one channel, so 64GB. It's possible Intel limits it to less, but if they're not enforcing the 16GB limit they've probably just left it default.

Another observation :

> Can confirm that Asus N100I-D D4 works with a 32gb Crucial stick. Model no. CT32G4SFD832A.

But a negative observation :

> Stick with 16GB. I tested with 32GB stick and I have to return it. I
> crashes.
>
> Clarification: the 32GB stick was not tested on EQ12. It's not
> possible (it's soldered w/ no expansion slot). I returned the EQ12 and
> tested a 32GB stick on a fanless N100 'firewall' PC I'm staring at
> now.

The conclusion seems to be that 32 GB was not validated by Intel, only
16 GB was validated. This means that it can work with more than 16 GB,
for RAM of a certain quality/type.

Buying your memory from a reputed vendor, you will have a better chance
of getting one that works. I would anyway ensure that the vendor
has a good return policy.

Comment: Doubling the addressable memory space is a matter of adding one bit to the address. At least that's what I learned in school. Seems that I have to trust the board vendor more than the Intel specs, at least when it comes to usable RAM. I am going to accept this as an answer cause I do not expect someone else to know much better ... Thank You!

Comment: Note that the doubling you mention is based on the nature of binary numbers. each digit to the left is equal to the sum of all digits on the right, + 1. eg 2 bits can express values up to 3 (11 => 3). a third bit allows you to store values up to 7 (100 = 4 and 111 = 7).  I personally found it a particularly valuable experience to learn to count binary on my fingers.